# Bind the NSArray in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xamarin.ios

I have method in static library `-(NSArray*)SetImage:(UIImage *)OcrImage;`.

I have to bind this method in MonoTouch as

`NSArray [] SetImage(UIImage OcrImage);`

and when I tried use method in monotouch class as

`NSArray[] wordArray=test.SetImage(this.imgSnapshot.Image);`

But app crashes when I call the method.

crash log

```
 System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_object_castclass (object,intptr)
at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.ArrayFromHandle[NSArray] (IntPtr handle) [0x0003a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray` is an array, so you don't want (**and can't**) add `[]` in your C# declaration.

If you know the *single* type being returned in the array (e.g. an array of `UIImage`) then you can bind this like:

```
UIImage [] SetImage(UIImage OcrImage);
```

Otherwise you can go the *general* way, like:

```
NSObject [] SetImage(UIImage OcrImage);
```

You can also bind this as an `NSArray` (without the `[]`) but that's rarely the best choice.